# Jquery DatePicker not getting displayed

Tags: jquery, struts2

I using struts2-jquery plugin for jquery. DatePicker is not getting displayed but a textfield is getting displayed.

I'm using the 2.3.1.1 version of struts & 3.2.0 version plugin of struts2-jquery-plugin.

JSP:

```
<sj:datepicker id = "date_from" name="dateFrom" label="Date From"
                    displayFormat="mm/dd/yy" value="today" buttonImage="true"></sj:datepicker>
```

What could be the probable reason for it?

Comment: Have you added jquery library before adding struts library?

Comment: are you including the tag lib on the top of your page as told by `Nrj` and `Avinash`.That is the first pointer for probable issues

Comment: I didnt include <sj:head/> tag. Workig fine after including it. Thanks Andrew, Avinash, Nrj & Umesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didnt include < sj:head /> tag.

Including it would fix the issue.

BR,
Shikha

Answer (score 1):

Use Little Java Code:

```
<sj:datepicker id = "date_from" name="dateFrom" label="Date From" displayFormat="mm/dd/yy" value="%{new java.util.Date()}" buttonImage="true"></sj:datepicker>
```